# Cannot connect to Docker daemon as non-root (sudo) even when being part of the docker group

Tags: permissions, docker

I am well-aware of [the official tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/) explaining how to use Docker as a non-root user.

Here is the error:

```
$ docker ps       
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://127.0.0.1:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
```

**The same command does work when running it as `sudo`.**

I'm part of the `docker` group:

```
$ groups ivan
ivan : ivan adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
```

`docker` seems to be the group handling the sock file:

```
$ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Jul  9 19:42 /var/run/docker.sock
```

My Ubuntu version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

**I also tried to log out and log in multiple times.**

What am I missing?

---

Here is the output of my docker service status in case it is useful:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-07-09 19:42:52 CEST; 23min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 21501 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 111
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─21501 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
           ├─21849 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 9200 -container-ip 172.19.0.2 -container-port 8080
           ├─21864 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 9150 -container-ip 172.19.0.3 -container-port 5432
           └─21877 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8080 -container-ip 172.24.0.2 -container-port 3000

Jul 09 19:42:47 MSI-Laptop dockerd[21501]: time="2019-07-09T19:42:47.589590860+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Jul 09 19:42:47 MSI-Laptop dockerd[21501]: time="2019-07-09T19:42:47.590011957+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Jul 09 19:42:49 MSI-Laptop dockerd[21501]: time="2019-07-09T19:42:49.517714365+02:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip ca
Jul 09 19:42:52 MSI-Laptop dockerd[21501]: time="2019-07-09T19:42:52.340024567+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Jul 09 19:42:52 MSI-Laptop dockerd[21501]: time="2019-07-09T19:42:52.428563147+02:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=481bc77 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=18.09.6
Jul 09 19:42:52 MSI-Laptop dockerd[21501]: time="2019-07-09T19:42:52.428665998+02:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Jul 09 19:42:52 MSI-Laptop dockerd[21501]: time="2019-07-09T19:42:52.442187808+02:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this was old but I ran into exact issue and almost searches don't help.
This problem causes by wrong DOCKER_HOST env we added when installing docker (for me the env added in ~/.profile). Check this file if you see:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

then remove it and run:

```
source ~/.profile
```

then restart docker service:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

done

Note: The DOCKER_HOST env only resetted in current terminal, we must restart the computer to make Docker works perfectly